# Error "Exception caught by widgets library ═Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget."

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, stack

I am trying to pass a class inside the Stack to the ListView, but it does not display on the screen as it should and gives an error

> Restarted application in 1 071ms.
>
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════ The following assertion was thrown
> while applying parent data.: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget Positioned(left: 154.0, top: 21.0, width: 73.0,
> height: 366.0) wants to apply ParentData of type StackParentData to a
> RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of
> incompatible type ParentData.
>
> Usually, this means that the Positioned widget has the wrong ancestor
> RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Positioned widgets are placed directly
> inside Stack widgets. The offending Positioned is currently placed
> inside a RepaintBoundary widget.
>
> The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the
> incompatible parent data was:   SizedBox ← Positioned ←
> MyRandomizedButton-[<'0'>] ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ←
> NotificationListener ← KeepAlive ←
> AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree-[Key <[<'0'>]>] ← SliverList ← ⋯
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
>
> #0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.
> #1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData
> #2      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject
> #3      RenderObjectElement.mount
> #4      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount ...     Normal element mounting (47 frames)
> #51     Element.inflateWidget
> #52     Element.updateChild
> #53     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild
> #54     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.
> #55     BuildOwner.buildScope
> #56     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild
> #57     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.
> #58     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.
> #59     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees
> #60     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback
> #61     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild
> #62     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild
> #63     RenderSliverList.performLayout
> #64     RenderObject.layout
> #65     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout
> #66     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout
> #67     RenderObject.layout
> #68     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence
> #69     RenderViewport._attemptLayout
> #70     RenderViewport.performLayout
> #71     RenderObject.layout
> #72     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #73     RenderObject.layout
> #74     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #75     RenderObject.layout
> #76     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #77     RenderObject.layout
> #78     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #79     RenderObject.layout
> #80     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #81     RenderObject.layout
> #82     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #83     RenderObject.layout
> #84     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #85     RenderObject.layout
> #86     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #87     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
> #88     RenderObject.layout
> #89     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #90     RenderObject.layout
> #91     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
> #92     RenderStack._computeSize
> #93     RenderStack.performLayout
> #94     RenderObject.layout
> #95     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
> #96     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
> #97     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
> #98     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
> #99     RenderObject.layout
> #100    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #101    RenderObject.layout
> #102    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #103    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
> #104    RenderObject.layout
> #105    MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
> #106    _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
> #107    MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
> #108    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
> #109    RenderObject.layout
> #110    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #111    RenderObject.layout
> #112    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #113    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
> #114    RenderObject.layout
> #115    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #116    RenderObject.layout
> #117    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #118    RenderObject.layout
> #119    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #120    RenderObject.layout
> #121    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #122    RenderObject.layout
> #123    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #124    RenderObject.layout
> #125    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #126    RenderObject.layout
> #127    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #128    RenderObject.layout
> #129    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #130    RenderObject.layout
> #131    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #132    RenderObject.layout
> #133    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #134    RenderObject.layout
> #135    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #136    RenderObject.layout
> #137    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #138    RenderObject.layout
> #139    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #140    RenderObject.layout
> #141    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #142    RenderObject.layout
> #143    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #144    RenderObject.layout
> #145    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #146    RenderObject.layout
> #147    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #148    RenderOffstage.performLayout
> #149    RenderObject.layout
> #150    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #151    RenderObject.layout
> #152    _RenderTheatre.performLayout
> #153    RenderObject.layout
> #154    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #155    RenderObject.layout
> #156    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #157    RenderObject.layout
> #158    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #159    RenderObject.layout
> #160    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #161    RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
> #162    RenderObject.layout
> #163    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #164    RenderObject.layout
> #165    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #166    RenderObject.layout
> #167    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #168    RenderObject.layout
> #169    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
> #170    RenderObject.layout
> #171    RenderView.performLayout
> #172    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
> #173    PipelineOwner.flushLayout
> #174    RendererBinding.drawFrame
> #175    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
> #176    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
> #177    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
> #178    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
> #179    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame. (elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer,
> dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════ Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════ Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════ Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════ Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

in the console. When I just pass the class inside the Stack by manually changing the Key, everything works as it should. How can I fix this?

The widget that gives an error:

```
class MainScreenWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreenWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreenWidget> createState() => _MainScreenWidgetState();
}

class _MainScreenWidgetState extends State<MainScreenWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return MyRandomizedButton(key: ValueKey(index.toString()));
              })

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update the MyRandomizedButton code and the complete error you are getting in your console.

You are using a positioned widget as the parent of the sized box which is creating an issue. The positioned widget can only be used inside a stack. So you can try to update your listview.builder inside a positioned widget instead of a sized box. Here is an example code. Let me know if this works for you.

```
class MainScreenWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreenWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreenWidget> createState() => _MainScreenWidgetState();
}

class _MainScreenWidgetState extends State<MainScreenWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final random = Random();

    int minT = 3;
    int maxT = maxHeight.toInt() - 80;
    int randomTop = minT + random.nextInt(maxT - minT);

    int minL = 3;
    int maxL = maxWidth.toInt() - 80;
    int randomLeft = minL + random.nextInt(maxL - minL);

    int minH = 70;
    int maxH = maxHeight.toInt() - randomTop;
    int randomHeight = minH + random.nextInt(maxH - minH);

    int minW = 70;
    int maxW = maxWidth.toInt() - randomLeft;
    int randomWidth = minW + random.nextInt(maxW - minW);

    int minR = 1;
    int maxR = 75;
    int randomRadius = minR + random.nextInt(maxR - minR);
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            height: randomHeight.toDouble(),
            width: randomWidth.toDouble(),
            top: randomTop.toDouble(),
            left: randomLeft.toDouble(),
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 5,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return MyRandomizedButton(key: ValueKey(index.toString()));
                }),
          )
          // MyRandomizedButton(key: ValueKey("0")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I made an update of the post

Comment: Check the updated code.

Comment: i try it and it fixed error in console but it doesn't work as intended

Comment: I think that using ListView is not suitable for my task. As I understand it, ListView displays elements under each other in a list, and this does not suit me, because in my task I need the buttons to occupy random positions on the screen and have a random size. Can you tell me how I can output a class containing them in a way similar to ListView (without manually prescribing it each time for a new button)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)

> A Positioned widget must be a descendant of a Stack.

Please Wrap your `Positioned` widget inside a stack

```dart
Stack(
children: [
    Positioned(
    /// remaining code
  ]
)
```

Comment: I tried and got this exception

_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart': Failed assertion: line 570 pos 12: 'size.isFinite': is not true.)

Line 570: "assert(size.isFinite);"

Comment: I just noticed that you have used stack in parent widget. Please refer to Pratul Pant's answer